# Changing Kendo tab strip text dynamically alters style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I need to change the Tab text dynamically and I can do that but when I change the text, the design changes and it looks bad.

Here's what I've got:

```js
$("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
    select: tabstrip_select
});

function tabstrip_select(e) {
    var x = e.item;
    $(x).text($(x).text() + ' - plus changed text');
    //alert('Tab text: ' + $(x).text());    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.1.322/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.1.322/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>   
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2011.3.1129/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabstrip">
    <ul>
        <li>Online</li>
        <li>Trading</li>
        <li>Whatever</li>
    </ul>
    <div style="min-height:350px;"></div>
    <div style="min-height:350px;"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLs7J/70/)

I don't know why is that screwed up after changing the text but what I need is to change the text without affecting anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function tabstrip_select(e) {
    $('#tabstrip ul li .k-link .plusText').remove();
    $(e.item).find('.k-link').append('<span class="plusText"> - plus changed text</span>'); 
}
```

you need add one more

```
<div style="min-height:350px;"></div>
```

**Update:**

```
function tabstrip_select(e) {
    var tab = $('#tabstrip ul li .k-link:contains("Online")');
    tab.find('.plusText').remove();
    tab.append('<span class="plusText"> - selected '+$(e.item).find('.k-link').text()+'</span>');
}
```

Comment: That works great! Can you do that for a tab that contains an exact string? Like, if the tab contains "whatever", then add text to that instead of the currently selected tab?

Comment: You change the text only if you select the "Online" tab - what I want is, no matter what tab you select, add some text to the "Online" tab, for example